# In Jmeter 2.4, for multiple users we are getting the same response

Tags: jmeter

`Thread Group
No of threads(users) = 5
Ramp-up period = 1
Loop Count = 1
    Simple Controller
        Login (We entered different user id 10100,10101...)
        Result Page (we are not getting response for the corresponding users)`

We used the View tree listener, to view our results.
We executed the 5 thread for 20 minutes, when i tried to view the results in 'View Result tree', in the request tab i am getting the different request parameter(10100,10101..) like this.
But in the response tab when i try to view the results by using 'render html' response data is not unique for the multiple requests.
Am getting the last requests response data for all the requests.

So please anybody can help me how to get different response for different unique requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you scaled down your test, to have 5 threads run the test only ONCE to see if the problem still occurs?

If the problem DOES occur you most likely need a cookie manager to ensure unique login.

If the problem DOES NOT occur, then there is probably a server issue that developers/system admins will need to help with.